# Cannot put winston inside a nodejs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I'm separating my application in modules, but each of these modules have functions that must me logged. So my idea was to create a file winstonConfig.js which would configure the winston, and then I'd `require` this file in each of the modules that need to log things. Here's winstonConfig.js:

```
var winston = require('winston');

winston.add(winston.transports.Riak, { level: 'warn' });

winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'mylogfile.log', level: 'silly' });

exports.log = winston.log;
exports.debug = winston.debug;
exports.error = winston.error;
```

(btw, is there a way to export everything once?)

but when I require('./winstonConfig.js') in my index.js, I get:

```
node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:481
  var instance = created ? transport : (new (transport)(options));
                                        ^

TypeError: transport is not a constructor
```

but the exact same code (without exports) will work without any problem when put in index.js (the problem is that then I cannot import this to other modules)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error with a new project, but when I was trying to use "logger.transports.DailyRotateFile". Then I realized that my code (that was copied from another project) just works for winston 1 (same version used on the other project). So, I just downgraded the lib to version 1 and everything worked normally:

```
$ npm uninstall winston --save
$ npm install winston@1.x.x --save
```

But if you want to use winston 2, I found the solution below to use DailyRotateFile - and, probably, there is a similar solution to use other kind of transports.

```
var winston = require('winston'), expressWinston = require('express-winston');
winston.transports.DailyRotateFile = require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing:

```
require('winston-riak');
```

I get the same error with your code.

If I comment out the addition of the Riak transport I get no error.

If I require winston-riak:

```
var winston = require('winston');
require('winston-riak');

winston.add(winston.transports.Riak, { level: 'warn' });
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'mylogfile.log', level: 'debug' });


exports.log = winston.log;
exports.debug = winston.debug;
exports.error = winston.error;
```

I get error: TypeError: riakjs.getClient is not a function. This appears to be because 'winston-riak' tries to execute riakjs.getClient(options) but, per https://github.com/mostlyserious/riak-js/issues/234, getClient is the exported function, rather than a method of the exported object. The winston-riak module hasn't been updated for 5 years. It seems it is not compatible with the current riak-js, which was updated 2 years ago.